# Determining if a decay is due to strong or weak interaction

Tags: nuclear-physics

How do we determine if a decay is due to weak or strong interaction. Is it true that as long as any one of the 6 flavour numbers are not conserved, then it must be due to weak interaction? Is there a good general rule of thumb to determine this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this correct.  The strong interaction cares *only* about the color charge, and doesn't care whether the color-charged objects are up quarks, charm quarks, or gluons.  The electric interaction cares *only* about electric charge, which brings in the charged leptons.  It's the weak interaction that segregates particles by their flavor.

You could say that only *because* the flavor interaction is weaker than the strong force or electromagnetism do we have the luxury of discussing particle flavor at all.

Experimentally there are other practical clues: weak decays tend to be much slower than strong or electromagnetic decays, and weak interactions strongly violate parity symmetry.